# Cannot retrieve next page link with javascript in scrapy and python

Tags: javascript, python, pagination, scrapy

I am having an issue getting a next page link with python.

**Code**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from gharbheti.items import GharbhetiItem
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.loader.processor import TakeFirst, Identity, MapCompose, Join, Compose
from urllib.parse import urljoin

    class ListSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'list'
    allowed_domains = ['gharbheti.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.gharbheti.com/sale','https://www.gharbheti.com/rent']

        def parse(self, response):
            properties=response.xpath('//li[@class="col-md-6 Search_building"]/descendant::a')
            for property in properties:
                link=property.xpath('./@href').extract_first()
                urls=response.urljoin(link)

                yield Request(urls,callback=self.parse_property, meta={'URL':urls, })

        def parse_property(self, response):
                l = ItemLoader(item=GharbhetiItem(), response=response)
                URL=response.meta.get('URL')
                l.add_value('URL', response.url)
                l.add_xpath('Title','//div[@class="product-page-meta"]/h4/em/text()',MapCompose(str.strip,str.title))
                l.add_xpath('Offering','//figcaption[contains(text(), "For Sale")]/text()|//figcaption[contains(text(),"For Rent")]/text()',MapCompose(lambda i:i.replace('For',''),str.strip))
                l.add_xpath('Price','//div[@class="deal-pricebox"]/descendant::h3/text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
                l.add_xpath('Type','//ul[@class="suitable-for"]/li/text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
                bike_parking=response.xpath('//i[@class="fa fa-motorcycle"]/following-sibling::em/text()').extract_first()
                car_parking=response.xpath('//i[@class="fa fa-car"]/following-sibling::em/text()').extract_first()
                parking=("Bike Parking: {} Car Parking: {}".format(bike_parking,car_parking))
                l.add_value('Parking',parking)
                l.add_xpath('Description','//div[@class="comment more"]/text()',MapCompose(str.strip))
                l.add_xpath('Bedroom','//i[@class="fa fa-bed"]/following-sibling::text()',MapCompose(lambda i:i.replace('Total Bed Room:',''),str.strip,int))
                l.add_xpath('Livingroom','//i[@class="fa fa-inbox"]/following-sibling::text()',MapCompose(lambda i:i.replace('Total Living Room:',''),str.strip,int))
                l.add_xpath('Kitchen','//i[@class="fa fa-cutlery"]/following-sibling::text()',MapCompose(lambda i:i.replace('Total kitchen Room:',''),str.strip,int))
                l.add_xpath('Bathroom','//i[@class="fa fa-puzzle-piece"]/following-sibling::text()',MapCompose(lambda i:i.replace('Total Toilet/Bathroom:',''),str.strip,int))
                l.add_xpath('Address','//b[contains(text(), "Map")]/text()',MapCompose(lambda i:i.replace('Map Loaction :-',''),str.strip))
                l.add_xpath('Features','//div[@class="list main-list"]/ul/li/text()',MapCompose(str.strip))

                images=response.xpath('//div[@class="carousel-inner dtl-carousel-inner text-center"]/descendant::img').extract()
                images=[s.replace('<img src="', '') for s in images]
                images=[i.split('?')[0] for i in images]
                Image=["http://www.gharbheti.com" + im for im in images]
                l.add_value('Images',Image)

                return l.load_item()
```

Cant retrieve next page from the network
    For another site, this is what I did (simple pagination without javascript

```
next_page=response.urljoin(response.xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Next")]/@href').extract_first()

yield Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question does not quite meet the standards that StackOverflow expects. Your question in its current state will likely not get accepted. I would highly suggest that you edit your question following the guidelines of [this StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the pagination uses javascript, there is no link in the page's source code.

To see what happening:

1. Open your browser's inspector (F12 in Chrome) and go to the network tab
2. Click the 'Load More' button on the webpage UI

The inspector will show you that the site is sending an async POST form request to `https://www.gharbheti.com/RoomRentHome/GetPropertiesForRent`, with two values for the form data:

1. `RentTypeId`: 0 {not sure what this is but I'm sure you can figure it out if you need to know}
2. `page`: 1 {gets incremented with every click on 'Load More'}

You'll have to take a programmatic approach using scrapy's [Form Request](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects). Looks like every page yields 10 more properties, so if you want to get the next 1000 after the initial page load you could write

```
for i in range(1,101):
    <send a form request with i as the page value>
```

I assume that the data format coming back from the POST is not the same as the site homepage, you so may have to define another callback function to parse that data.

Comment: Thank you. So I understand there should be another parsing function and use xpaths according to the form request.Any best practices i should follow would be good to know.

Comment: @shovanrai Yes, once you successfully get a response from the FormRequest, you'll know what kind of parsing you'll have to do. I recommend using the `scrapy shell` for those steps.